# Opening the first element of an accordion after a tab change and ajax call

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a page containing several jquery tabs.  When I load the page, an ajax call reads a text file and processes it using the following function.

```
function fnSetUpAccordion(){
$('.accord > fieldset:not(:first)').hide(); 
$('.accord > h3:first').addClass('close');
$('.accord > h3').click(function() { 
   $(this).toggleClass('open').siblings('h3.close').removeClass('close');$(this).next('fieldset').slideToggle('1500').siblings('fieldset:visible').slideUp('1000');
    return false;
});
```

This does what it is supposed to do when the page is first loaded - close all accordion elements except the first one.

However, when I click on a new tab and load another file into that tab and apply the same function to the incoming text stream, the first accordion element in the new tab remains closed.

What is the mistake I'm making?

Thanks/Thomas

Comment: It sounds like you need to re-register your elements, or use `.on`. Could be wrong though

Comment: Provide your markup and a little more on how you call the function. ... It appears you may have to maintain context within the function instead of using `.accord > ....` which will alway affect the same (wrong) elements. Also consider using a delegated event.

Comment: Thanks for the direction @PeterKA - the context was the key.